# jQuery function is not available in Promise.then()

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am implementing a threaded comment board on my website with [this jQuery library](https://github.com/Viima/jquery-comments).

Here is a part of my `index.html` where comment data are downloaded from Firebase and displayed in the front end through the library.

For an experiment, I tried to display a comment board in an element (e.g. `body`).
In the first code below, it does not throw any error. However, this is not the right place to call the comment board function because the function has to use the data from Firebase.

So, I moved the jQuery function to the `then` method of `db.collection` (second code) so that the comment function can all the data from Firebase (stored in `querySnapshot`).

Then the second one throws the error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...).comments is not a function

Why is this happening? How can the jQuery function correctly use the data from Firebase?

---

First code

```
<script>
window.onload = () => {
  $("body").comments({
    profilePictureURL: 'sample-icon.png',
    getComments: (success, error) => {
      var commentsArray = [{
          ...
      }];
      success(commentsArray);
    }
  });
  const db = firebase.firestore()
  db.collection("projects").get().then(querySnapshot => {
   ...
  })
}
</script>
```

Second code

```
<script>
window.onload = () => {
  const db = firebase.firestore()
  db.collection("projects").get().then(querySnapshot => {
    $("body").comments({
      profilePictureURL: 'sample-icon.png',
      getComments: (success, error) => {
        var commentsArray = [{
          ...
        }];
        success(commentsArray);
      }
    });
  })
}
</script>
```

Here is a part of the file structure of my website

```
/public        <--- Hosting on Firebase
  index.html
  /forum
    index.html <--- the index.html shown in the question above
  /css
    jquery-comment.css <--- from the jQuery library
  /js
    jquery-comment.js <---  from the jQuery library
```

Comment: There's no reason, in the code you have shown, for ` $(...).comments()` to throw. It would appear that somewhere else in your code either (a) the comments plugin becomes uninstalled from jQuery or (b) the `$` member is overwritten with another instance of jQuery and that instance doesn't have the comments plugin installed. Either way, by the time the `.then()` callback fires (in a later event thread), `$` (ie jQuery) does not have a `comments` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<script>
window.onload = () => {
  const db = firebase.firestore()
  // use a closure
  const jq = $;
  db.collection("projects").get().then(querySnapshot => {
    jq("body").comments({
      profilePictureURL: 'sample-icon.png',
      getComments: (success, error) => {
        var commentsArray = [{
          ...
        }];
        success(commentsArray);
      }
    });
  })
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked! Could you give me some information about the problem? What was the cause of the problem (like scope etc)? Any documentation or link is highly appreciated. This workaround looks simple and beautiful but I still don't quite understand it.

Comment: This solution masks the problem. See my comment above for an explanation of what is actually going on.